# Unable to push 'heroku master'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, ssh

When I tried to run 'git push heroku master', I got the error

```
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I run the command 'ssh -vvv git@heroku.com' to know what is happening, the result is

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.3, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com [50.19.85.154] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 50.19.85.154 port 22: No route to host
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com [50.19.85.132] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 50.19.85.132 port 22: No route to host
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com [50.19.85.156] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 50.19.85.156 port 22: No route to host
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: No route to host
```

I'm a newbie to deployment and ssh. Please help.

Comment: can you try `ping heroku.com` ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried pinging, it's 100% packet loss. Most probably McAffe  service in college server has blocked it (We have a college proxy for internet access). I will try other network.